# Howto get device's features with adb

Tags: adb, hardware

Howto get device's features with `adb` i.e. whether it has e.g. accelerometer, screen is capable landscape mode, etc.

These values are set in XML during build:

```
<feature name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
<feature name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sdk:

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

Complete list:

```
adb shell getprop
```

Through the package manager:

```
adb shell pm list features
```

Comment: @pevik it added a space in there I didn't catch, but fixed now. Thanks for the proofread. Glad that this helped.

Comment: Thanks, `adb shell pm list features` was the one I didn't know. BTW: Complete list is: `adb shell getprop` _(Sep 9 '14 at 8:52, edited)_